# Why is my Express server response truncating during SSR only?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js

I am using Next.js, Redux, and Express. My page has this code:

```
static async getInitialProps({store, isServer, pathname, query}) {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/tutorials');
  const tutorials = await res.json();
  store.dispatch(tutorialsReceived({tutorials}));
}
```

I get the React debug error saying my server response is different than my client. It's expecting a very long JSON response (252KB), and the server render is getting cut off incredibly early. I have tried two ways to send the file and am unsure why either would cut short.

```
// Try 1
server.get('/tutorials', (req, res) => {
  fs.createReadStream('./common/content.json').pipe(res);
});

// Try 2
server.get('/tutorials', (req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('./common/content.json', 'utf8', function(err, tutorials) {
    res.send(tutorials);
  });
});
```

Modifying the file to be smaller like `{a:1,b:2,c:3}` results in no error for my sanity check.

Comment: Can you verify if your JSON file is properly formatted?

Comment: Yeah it's fine as the client handles it no problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like express is setting wrong `Content-Length` header in the response due to which your JSON gets chopped off. You can set it explicitly and that should work.

```
server.get('/tutorials', (req, res) => {
    fs.readFile('./common/content.json', 'utf8', function (err, tutorials){
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(tutorials, 'utf8')
        })
        res.send(tutorials);
    });
});
```

Comment: Cool I went with the `res.set` syntax but not having `Content-Length` was the answer!